# Poner "this: any" dentro de un function

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

No sé cual es la razón de que tenga que ponerun "this.any" dentro del "function" cunado lamo al "comparar password" en este modelo de datos:

```
import { Schema, model, Document } from 'mongoose';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';


const usuarioSchema = new Schema({

nombre: {
    type: String,
    required: [ true, 'El nombre es necesario' ]
},
avatar: {
    type: String,
    default: 'av-1.png'
},
email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: [ true, 'El correo es necesario' ]
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required: [ true, 'La contraseña es necesaria']
}

});


usuarioSchema.method('compararPassword', function(this: any ,password: string = ''): boolean {

if (  bcrypt.compareSync( password, this.password) ) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}

});



interface IUsuario extends Document {
nombre: string;
email: string;
password: string;
avatar: string;

compararPassword(password: string): boolean;
}





export const Usuario = model<IUsuario>('Usuario', usuarioSchema);

Si no lo hago obtengo un error.Pero no sé cual es la razón de que tenga que poner "this.any"       dentro del function para poder así acceder a la porpiedad "password" externa a la función.
```

Creo que debe ser algo debido a usar funciones de flecha o funciones normales para accecer a propiedades de fuera usando "this."

HE buscado e internet pero no veo ninguna documentación al respecto.

Comment: ¿Y puedes poner un ejemplo de cómo usas ese método de instancia?

Comment: Eso es *typescript*, ¿ Cierto ? ¿ No te funciona con `this: Schema` ?